# dd partition image differs

Tags: linux, dd, diskimage

What variables can produce different md5sum of the same dd image of a partition?
If I execute this code over two storages (same size, brand and geometry) why I obtain different "partition.image" files:

```
sfdisk /dev/sda < /partition.table
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/
tar -xf somefiles.tar -C /mnt/
umount /mnt
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/partition.image
```

P.S. tar is preserving all files timings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time of creation, access etc. And that's good - no two images, created at different storages should be the same. Or otherwise, you could have something called "collision".

Comment: The filesystem is extracted from a tar preserving all file timings!

Answer (score 1):

When you make a new ext4 filesystem with the mkfs utility, it generates a unique UUID between invocations(unless you pass the -U option with an explicit UUID).  Since the UUID is stored in the superblock of the file system, the images you generate between different runs of the above code will **not** be bit-for-bit identical.

Sources: http://wiki.debian.org/fstab#UUIDs
         https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#The_Super_Block